# How can I install assets in web/css/ folder

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I have installed Symfony 2.8 and I have put header.css in web/css, but I don't know how can I access it.
The web browser returns the following error:

```
GET http://www.grupoinversores.com/css/header.css 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need symlink. For example... here you `js, css, img` directories:

```
AppBundle/Resources/public/
```

In console command `$ php app/console assets:install --symlink` creates symlink for this `js, css, img` directories for `AppBundle/Resources/public/`.

Now you `js, css, img` here: `web/bundles/app/css`, `web/bundles/app/js`, `web/bundles/app/img` and for currect generate path use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/style.css') }}">
```

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command

Answer (score 0):

it seems based on live page as I looked there you have created a  "header.css" directory not a file. No 404, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Twig? Can you post the part of your HTML that tries to call your header.css file?

If you are using Twig, have you tried something like:

```
<link href="{{ asset('cms-assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

inside your HTML?

In my case the bootstrap.css file is inside the folder:

> /web/cms-assets/css/bootstrap

And as seen, I can access it using the "asset" with Twig